# Can $\sum_{k=0}^n p_k g^{(k)}$ be zero when $g \neq 0$ and the $p_k$'s are polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $p_1, \dots, p_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be polynomials such that at least one of them is non-zero. Further, let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb R$ with support in $[0,1]$ and which does not vanish identically. Can it happen, that the function
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n p_k g^{(k)}
$$
vanishes identically, where $g^{(k)}$ denotes the $k$-th derivative of $g$?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on if $p_n$ has roots in $[0,1]$.

If not, then you get a simple linear DE with continuous coefficients where all solutions for any initial state are defined on $[0,1]$.

If $p_n$ has roots inside the interval, then the homogeneous DE has singular points. In the case that they are regular singular points, it might be possible to arrange a piecewise solution that extends to a $C^\infty$ function over the full interval.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Does your answer also consider the fact that $g$ is globally $C^\infty$ but has support in $[0,1]$?. So $g \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: No, I did not consider that. You can do some strange constructions like $y=\exp(-1/(x(1-x)))$ with $x^2(1-x)^2y'+(1-2x)y=0$, which is not regular singular at the roots, and despite or because of this allows such a solution.